# Why my code faster on Linux than on RTOS?

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I wrote a Matrix class in C++, I made a benchmark to test this code on a Raspberry Pi, when I used arch Linux the calculation time was 0.4ms, When I used ChibiOS which is RTOS the runtime of the code was 2.5ms. The CPU frequency both case was the same(700Mhz). Can be that the memory operations(calloc, memcpy) is slower in one system?

Comment: What compilers are you using the two cases? With which optimization options?

Comment: Any particular reason why you think that an RTOS should be faster?

Comment: because don't have that many processes on the rtos

Comment: That is far too short of a run time to really compare quantitatively. You need to lengthen the run time, and in all likelihood run it many times and average to find an actual estimate of cost.

Comment: Do you use any floating point math? If so, it's hard float versus soft float. You'll have to look closely at both cases to see what accounts for the difference. But generally speaking, an RTOS will be slower than a general-purpose OS. Real time capability has a significant performance cost. If it didn't, general purpose OSes would be real time too. (And to the extent they are, for example media handling in Windows, it does come with a significant performance penalty.)

Comment: Real-time is about latency, not throughput.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Specifically, it's about sacrificing throughput and average latency in exchange for more *predictable* latency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using doubles, it's [hard float](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#What_is_Raspbian.3F) versus soft float.

Note that you must not attempt to run hard float binaries on an OS that doesn't support hard float. If you do, it will appear to work until there's a context switch between two processes that use hard float. Since the OS won't save the floating point state on context switches, they'll step on each other's floating point contexts and results will be unpredictable.

I believe the linker will catch this, so unless you write the assembly yourself and don't use any libraries, it should be difficult to run into this problem accidentally.

Comment: I compiled with hard float support and now the runtime is 1.9ms from 2.5ms.  but it still far away from 0.4ms. Is it possible that this is a cross compiler optimization problem?

Comment: @iUngi: It could be. You'd have to profile it (or compare the raw assembly) to figure that out. Does it make a lot of system calls? If so, pre-emption checks could be the issue.